# MyPy: Incompactible arg-type for a property

Tags: python

I am working on python web app. I have defined an `enum` as below:

```
class AccountTypes(StrEnum):
   A: str = "aaa"
   B: str = "bbb"
```

Then, I have a `class` as below:

```
class Account:
    
    _types: type[AccountTypes] = AccountTypes


    @classmethod
    def types(cls) -> type[AccountTypes]:

        return cls._types
```

Then, I have defined `usecase` as below:

```
class AccountUsecase:

  @classmethod
  def types(cls) -> type[AccountTypes]:
     
       return Account.types()
```

Then, I have defined a `service` as below:

```
class AccountService:

   Types = property(fget=AccountUsecase.types)
```

I am using `service` inside `infra/web` as below:

```
if account_type == AccountService.Types.A:
   # some code to execute
```

On running the code, I am getting an error in the `service` file as below:

```
 error: Argument "fget" to "property" has incompatible type "Callable[[], Type[AccountTypes]]"; expected "Optional[Callable[[Any], Any]]"  [arg-type]
```

What I am missing?

Comment: The getter of a property instance expects to receive an instance of `AccountService` as an argument. You might want a "class property", though such a thing doesn't really exist and the current behavior that allows `@classmethod` and `@property` to stack is deprecated.

Comment: Hi chepner, Thanks. I made the changes as you suggested, I modified it to `instance` method and passed with the `AccountService` instance. It is working now.